# Visual Basic Number Mapping

Tags: math, vb6

I am writing a program that converts the screen mapped pixels to actual resolution. As an example on the screen the co-ordinates are from (0,0) [top left] to (1,1) [bottom right]. My computer monitor has the resolution of 1600x900. So i need a way to map (0,0) to (0X0) and (1,1) to (1600x900) as well as everything in between such as (0.56,0.7) to Whatever it translates to in resolution. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to scale them like this:

**To go from actual to co-ordinates:**

> x = x * actualmax/coordmax

so in your example, using a y-coordinate of 0.333

> x = 0.333 * 900/1 = 300

**To go from co-ordinates to actual:**

> x = x * coordmax/actualmax

so in your example, using a y-coordinate of 300

> x = 300 * 1/900 = 0.333

Comment: Thank you for that answer, i have one more question what if the minimum wasn't (0,0)? As in the actual was (0.14,0.15) to (1,1) how would that change the equation?

Comment: @Mark, sorry missed your comment.  Try newx = lowactualmin + (highcoordmax - lowcoordmin)/(highactualmax - lowactualmin).